# Erro na validação do jwt token, Spring secutiry

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, spring-security, filter

Olá, estou criando uma api para uso em uma farmácia. Na hora de implementar o security, jwt token e o filter para utilização da segurança, acontece um erro na hora da validação das requisições e o token simplesmente não é considerado válido. Ele possui um tempo de expiração de 2 horas, o usuário tem a liberação para realizar o login, eu faço isso via postman, pego o token que aparece, copio e colo na validação authorization, realizo uma requisição protegida no postman e simplesmente tomo um forbidden403. Estou utilizando o método post para realizar essa requisição, e o bearer Token para enviar.
No código como podem ver tem toda a configuração correta para o meu filter vir antes do filter do spring e também tem a configuração para demonstrar até onde o código está rodando, com um system.out com a mensagem ("chamando filter"), o que indica que o código roda até a validação do token e depois da problema.

Obs: Estou usando mysql, springboot 3.0 e java 17. Toda a estrutura das tabelas já está criada e funcionando, porém não consigo fazer nenhuma requisição além do login após enfrentar esse erro de validação.

Segue o código abaixo:

```java
Entidade Usuário:
@Table(name = "usuarios")
@Entity(name = "Usuario")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of ="id")
public class Usuario implements UserDetails{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return senha;
    }
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return login;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Authentication Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class AutenticacaoController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager manager;
    
    @Autowired
    private TokenService tokenService;
    
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<DadosTokenJWT> efetuarLogin(@RequestBody @Valid DadosAutenticacao dados) {
        var authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(dados.login(), dados.senha());
        var authentication = manager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
        
        var tokenJWT = tokenService.gerarToken((Usuario) authentication.getPrincipal());
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new DadosTokenJWT(tokenJWT));
    }
}
```

SecutiryConfigurations:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecutiryConfigurations {
    
    @Autowired
    private SecutiryFilter securityFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception{
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder () {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }       
}
```

Token Service:

```java
@Service
public class TokenService {

    @Value("${api.security.token.secret}")
    private String secret;

    public String gerarToken(Usuario usuario) {
        try {
            var algoritmo = Algorithm.HMAC256(secret);
            return JWT.create().withIssuer("API remedios_api").withSubject(usuario.getLogin())
                    .withExpiresAt(dataExpiracao()).sign(algoritmo);
        } catch (JWTCreationException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao gerar Token JWT", exception);
        }
    }
    

    public String getSubject(String tokenJWT) {
        try {
            var algoritmo = Algorithm.HMAC256(secret);
            return JWT.require(algoritmo).withIssuer("API remedios_api").build().verify(tokenJWT).getSubject();

        } catch (JWTVerificationException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Token inválido ou expirado");
        }
    }
    

    private Instant dataExpiracao() {

        return LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(2).toInstant(ZoneOffset.of("-03:00"));
    }
}
```

SecurityFilter:

```java
@Component
public class SecutiryFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
    
    @Autowired
    private TokenService  tokenService;
    
    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository repository;
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        var tokenJWT = recuperarToken(request);
        System.out.println("Chamando Filter");
        if(tokenJWT != null) {
            var subject = tokenService.getSubject(tokenJWT);
            var usuario = repository.findByLogin(subject);
            var authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(usuario, null, usuario.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            System.out.println("Logado na requisição");
        }
    
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String recuperarToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        var authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if( authorizationHeader != null) {
            return authorizationHeader.replace("Bearer", "");
        }
        return null;        
    }
}
```

Ficarei muito grato pela ajuda.

Comment: o seu replace no bearer deveria ter um espaço, ex authorizationHeader.replace("Bearer ", ""); se você colocar apenas bearer o token vai ficar " sequenciaDeValoresDoToken" e provavelmente vai ficar invalido na hora da checagem

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!"